# Installing local checks for Check_MK's agent

Tags: monitoring, local, agent, check-mk

I'm trying to write local checks for a Check_MK instance on a computer with OMD installed. I don't have admin rights on this machine, so I work as an OMD site like this:

```
sudo omd su $MY_SITE
```

And, like my standard user, the site user does not have admin rights either.

In the [Check_MK documentation for writing agent-based checks](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_devel_agentbased.html) I find that I have two options for doing this:

1. Editing `/usr/bin/check_mk_agent`, which is impossible with the rights I have or
2. Creating a script in `/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/plugins/`, which is also impossible because this folder is only writeable to root.

When I run `cmk --paths` I see that there's a folder for "locally installed agents and plugins" at `$MY_SITE_HOME/local/share/check_mk/agents/`. This folder has a subfolder named `plugins`. If I put a script in there, however, its output doesn't show up when I run `check_mk -d localhost`. It is set to be executable and it does produce valid output, as far as I can tell:

```
<<<helloworld>>>
Hello world!
```

Am I putting the script in the wrong folder? Is it necessary to have admin rights in order to write agent based checks in Check_MK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this without admin rights would have been to edit `main.mk` to include [include a new datasource program](http://mathias-kettner.de/checkmk_datasource_programs.html). I would have liked to have a local folder that was analog to `/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/plugins/`, but it seems that this is not possible. I ended up having one of our admins give me the rights to `/usr/lib/check_mk_agent/plugins/`.